# Window flowable based on a property

Tags: java, kotlin, rx-java, reactive-programming

I have a stream of events that contain a time (`Instant`). I want to create chunks starting from the first time of a given size (`Duration`). I also want to emit the empty chunks if nothing came in during a set time.

**An example:**

Input: `[t0, t1, t2, t3, t7, t8, t9, t10]`

Output with window size 2: `[[t0, t1], [t2, t3], [], [t7], [t8, t9], [t10]]`

**Problem:**

I have tried creating an auxiliary window publisher that will emit the instants at which the new window should be created. I am sharing what I have below for reference, but it's not functional.

**Code:**

```
/**
 * Creates a [Flowable] of chunks of time. It may return empty chunks
 * if nothing happened during the set period.
 *
 * ie: [1, 2, 3, 4] -> [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
 */
fun <T : TimeAware> Flowable<T>.timeChunks(size: Duration, startAt: Instant? = null): TimeChunksFlowable<T> {
    return TimeChunksFlowable(this, size, startAt)
}

class TimeChunksFlowable<T : TimeAware> (
    private val source: Flowable<T>,
    val size: Duration,
    private var startAt: Instant? = null
) : Flowable<TimeBracketFlowable<T>>() {

    init {
        require(!size.isNegative && !size.isZero) { "Size must be positive: $size" }
    }

    override fun subscribeActual(s: Subscriber<in TimeBracketFlowable<T>>) {
        source
            .publish { it.window() }
            .subscribe(s)
    }

    private fun Flowable<T>.window(): Flowable<TimeBracketFlowable<T>> {
        val chunks = chunks()
        return window(chunks).brackets(chunks)
    }

    private fun Flowable<Flowable<T>>.brackets(starts: Flowable<Instant>): Flowable<TimeBracketFlowable<T>> {
        val bi = BiFunction { f: Flowable<T>, i: Instant -> f.timeBracket(i, i + size) }
        return zipWith(starts, bi)
    }

    /**
     * Creates a helper [Flowable] which emits an event every time we need to create a new chunk.
     */
    private fun Flowable<T>.chunks(): ChunkStartsFlowable<T> {
        return ChunkStartsFlowable(this, size, startAt)
    }

    private class ChunkStartsFlowable<T : TimeAware> (
        private val source: Flowable<T>,
        private val size: Duration,
        private val startAt: Instant?
    ) : Flowable<Instant>() {

        override fun subscribeActual(s: Subscriber<in Instant>) {

            val subscriber = InternalSubscriber<T>(size, startAt)
            source.subscribe(subscriber)
            subscriber.publisher.subscribe(s)
        }

        private class InternalSubscriber<T : TimeAware> (
            private val size: Duration,
            private var startAt: Instant?
        ) : Subscriber<T> {

            val publisher = UnicastProcessor.create<Instant>()

            override fun onSubscribe(s: Subscription) {
                publisher.onSubscribe(s)
            }

            override fun onNext(t: T) {
                var start = startAt ?: t.time

                // add empty chunks since nothing happened
                while (start + size <= t.time) {
                    publisher.onNext(start)
                    start += size
                }

                startAt = start
            }

            override fun onError(t: Throwable) {
                publisher.onError(t)
            }

            override fun onComplete() {
                startAt?.apply(publisher::onNext)
                publisher.onComplete()
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:** After thinking more about this problem, I found that buffer should be enough:

```java
upstream.buffer(
    windowSize.toMillis(),
    windowSize.toMillis(),
    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```